# nginx-ingress path based angular application

Tags: kubernetes, angular-routing, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

I have an angular application which is dockerized using nginx-alpine as base image. My infra is hosted on AKS cluster version 1.18.14 . And nginx-ingress to route traffic to pods k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/controller:v0.44.0 . Below is my Ingress

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
 rules:
  - http:
     paths:
      - path: /?(.*)
        backend:
        serviceName: portal
        servicePort: 80
```

When I hit the application with ***ip-address/*** application loads .
But If I want to add path to it with below nginx-ingress app doesn't load.

```
 - path: /myportal(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: my-portal
          servicePort: 80
```

WHen I hit ***ip-address/myportal*** app doesn't load. What changes should I make

Comment: Have you seen [this example](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/)?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a mistake in your yaml config.

It should be:

```
  paths:
  - backend:
      serviceName: my-portal
      servicePort: 80
    path: /myportal(/|$)(.*)
```

instead of:

```
 - path: /myportal(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: my-portal
          servicePort: 80
```

Make sure the indentation are in place and syntax is correct. Use [this example](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/) as a reference.